# Deck of cards using a 3 dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, random

I'm making a deck of cards with a 3 dimensional array. But when I call the random card method, it says the card array has a null value even the I should be filling it with a double for loop?

I've looked up other posts on cards, but they are usually a 2 D or two different arrays, not 3D. Thanks for any of you time. If I'm way off in my coding/thoughts/post, please let me know, I'm pretty new to Java and stack.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Deck {

    String Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs;
    private String Suit;
    private int Deck [][][];
    private int card [][];


    public void FreshDeck()
    {
        Deck = new int [][][]
                   {{{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1},{7,1},{8,1},{9,1},{10,1},{11,1},{12,1}},       //Hearts 
                    {{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,2},{8,2},{9,2},{10,2},{11,2},{12,2}},       //Diamonds 
                    {{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3},{6,3},{7,3},{8,3},{9,3},{10,3},{11,3},{12,3}},       //Spades
                    {{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4},{6,4},{7,4},{8,4},{9,4},{10,4},{11,4},{12,4}}        //Clubs
                   };   
    }

    private void setValue(int index, int value)
        {
            card[index][0] = value;
        }
    private void setSuit(int index, int suit)
        {
            card[index][1] = suit;
        }
    public int Value(int index)
        {
        return card[index][0];
        }
    public int Suit(int index)
        {
        return card[index][1];
        }

    public void setRandomCard()
    {
    Random randomCard = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomCard.nextInt(51);
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
            {
                card[i][j] = Deck[randomInt][i][j];
            }
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't 2D work for you?

Comment: Please respect the Java naming convention, for you and the people that will have to read your code. No upper case at the beginning of a variable or a method, only for classes and interfaces.

Comment: I can't see any reason to have a 3D `Deck` or a 2D `card`. If it's for some relational purposes consider writing another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so based on how you have declared and initialized `Deck`, you have:

- an array representing the suites: indexes go from zero to 3
- within those, you have an array representing the cards in a suite: indexes go from zero to 12,
- within that, each card is represented as an array with a 2 elements representing the suite number and the card within the suite.

Then you attempt to select a random card as follows:

```
    card[i][j] = Deck[randomInt][i][j];
```

But `randomInt` is a number between zero and 51.  That ain't going to work is it.  And `card` is a 2D array of ints ... not a 2D array of `int[]` like `Deck`.

It is just a mess.

---

Frankly, you are better off starting again.

My recommendation:

- Don't use arrays for this.  Java is an object-oriented language and works best if you design and code following the O-O paradigm.
- Declare a `Card` class to represent a card.  It has two immutable fields; i.e. the suite and the value.
- Use one of the standard list classes, and create a `List<Card>` to represent each deck (or hand) of cards.

Also, use standard Java identifier conventions.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! I think I will just start over.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2D array, if you must use arrays. Your 3D data structure is redundant because you're already indicating suit by the first dimension, but then you include a suit indicator again in the third dimension.

```
int[][] hearts = Deck[0]; // first element in first dimension is hearts suit
int[] aceOfHearts = hearts[0]; // first element in second dimension is ace
int heartsIndicator = aceOfHearts[1]; // redundant hearts indicator in 3rd dimension
```

By the way, your deck has no kings.

Answer (score 1):

The first dimension of your 3D array is the suit (0 to 3), the second is a card (0 to 11, no kings?) and the third is the card (0 for the value and 1 for the suit).

If you want to draw a card, it would be something like this: `card[] = deck[0-3][0-11];` (you'll get a `card` where `card[0]` is the value and `card[1]` the suit). You need to randomize these 2 parameters to get a random card.

Instead of using multidimensional arrays, you should use objects (for example, make a class for cards, one for the deck). The code would be more understandable (+ all the benefits of object oriented programming!).

Comment: Different classes. Got it. Thanks!